# C- Not able to index string array if not declared in function scope

Tags: c, operating-system, kernel

I am developing my kernel and it has been alright so far. However, there is one (possibly trivial) problem. I can't index a string array if it is not declared in my function scope but the global one. This is where the error is:

```
unsigned char *exception_messages[32] = {
    "Division by Zero Exception!\n\r",
    "Debug Exception!\n\r",
    ....
    "Reserved Exception!\n\r"
    "Reserved Exception!\n\r"
};


void fault_handler(struct regs *r) {
    if(r->int_no < 32) {
        int a = r->int_no;
        char* str = exception_messages[a]; // no matter what the value of 'a' is, I only get "S " printed onto the screen.
        puti(a);
        puts("\n\r");
        puts(str);
        puts("System Halted!\n\r");
        for (;;);
    }
}
```

And it works just fine if I declare the array inside the function itself but I don't want to push and pop so many things onto the stack every time the user presses a key or something!

Comment: And the `puts` function works as it should? Literal strings works otherwise?

Comment: On a (probably) unrelated note, it's usually `"\r\n"` and not the opposite.

Comment: I feel `"\n\r"` is safer, knowing the implementation of my driver. Maybe it is just how I write on paper which has lead to this. I am too lazy to change it now.

Comment: You are sure the array, when declared globally, is accessible in kernel memory space?

Comment: And yeah, `puts` works just fine

Comment: What is the question? You are not actually pushing many things on the stack, so what? And that code is legal... What is your problem actually? You can also eliminate `int a` and `char *str` is you wish.

Comment: Probably not the problem but why are you using `unsigned char*` which differs from your assignment to `char*`?

Comment: OMG thank you @HansPetterTaugbølKragset. I now load 20 sectors instead of 10 and I am able to see the string! Thank You!

Comment: No problem :) In kernel development, moving things around and getting different behaviour is for the most part a memory issue :)

Comment: Are you sure that `r->int_nr`is >= 0?

Comment: @HansPetterTaugbølKragset You could now post the first comment as the answer to the question.